# HTTP Live Streaming not working with a camera source

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am trying to create a live stream over HTTP using GStreamer with a `tcamsrc`. I used the following command for the HLS sink:

```
sudo gst-launch-1.0 tcamsrc serial=<id> ! video/x-bayer,format=bggr,width=1280, \
height=960,framerate=15/1 ! capssetter join=false replace=true caps="video/x-bayer, \
format=rggb,width=1280, height=960,framerate=15/1" ! tcamwhitebalance ! \
tcamautoexposure ! capssetter join=false replace=true caps="video/x-bayer, \
format=bggr,width=1280,height=960,framerate=15/1" ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! \
video/x-raw,format=I420 ,width=1280, height=960,framerate=15/1 ! videoscale ! \
video/x-raw,format=I420,width=800,height=600,framerate=15/1 ! x264enc ! \
video/x-h264, profile=main ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5
```

This results in a static video player that does not play the stream, even when you click on the play button. I host it via a `jetty` server and this is what gets displayed in the browser:
[image]
The `ts` files are correctly generated and the `m3u8` playlist is found successfully (the player gives an error otherwise). I assume I somehow incorrectly convert the stream from a `x-raw` format to `x-h264`, but I couldn't get it to work using various GStreamer elements.

I am running this on `OS X Yosemite 10.10.5` and the Safari version is `Version 10.1 (10603.1.30.0.34)`.

Comment: Was a solution found?

Comment: No really, unfortunately.